# how can i do this functions and to make a image renning in spicial time?

Tags: javascript

The gallery has to contain the following:
1- A place to put the image in.
2- Initially, the gallery contains 3 images.
3- The images presented in sequence automatically every 2 seconds.
4- A button to add extra image, the name of the image is written in a special text box (maximum 10 images).
5- A button to delete the current image (until they are 3 images, the gallery must not contain less than 3 images).
6- Buttons to move in the gallery (Forward and Backward, taking into account it is circular gallery).
7- Each image is clickable, in which when an image is clicked, it appears in a separate place (of course the gallery keeps evolving the images).
8- A list contains the names of the images, so that when an image name is selected, it appears in the gallery.
9- Two buttons: begin and end, the first displays the first image, and the second displays the last image.
10- In all of the operations of the gallery, it keeps on in displaying images in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically need a carousel ?
here is one:

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

You're welcome.